# How to remove recent templates in Microsoft Word on the Home screen?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, templates

So, I made the mistake of opening a few Business Card templates from the Microsoft Word library.

Now I am greeted with fluffy pastel colors every time I startup the program, or use **"File" > "New"**

When right-clicking these items, the only options are "Preview", "Create" and "Pin to list" (aren't they *already* pinned to the list? I can't get rid of them!) They do not respond to the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. They cannot be dragged to the edge of the screen.

Product is Microsoft Office Professional 2013.

**Is there any way to remove these recent items?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those screens only show the last custom template you opened. Choose something else that is less obnoxious to you and that will replace the offending one.

For a more radical approach to try you can clear Recent entirely by going to File > Options > Advanced > Display and reset the number of recent files to display to zero and set it back later. I can't recall if that will also clear the last template accessed, but if you don't like my first suggestion you can try this one. I won't test it right now because of a project I'm working on, and my recent list is important to me so I don't want to clear it.

Comment: I had foolishly only checked `File > Options > Display` instead of `File > Options > Advanced > Display`. That reset the Home screen, and now it shows an enormous list of suggested templates from Microsoft, instead. But it's better than it was!

Answer (score 1):

I had to try the radical approach. It did not work.

But there's a yet more radical way to do it:
Modifying the registry.
Assume the file that has been deleted has the name 'MyTemplate.dotx'.
Go to 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER'. No use to start "earlier". (It works to start at "Computer" but it will take unnecessarily extra time...).
Search for 'MyTemplate'.
Make sure that all 'Keys','Values,'Data' are all 3 checked.
You will find it in a string value named 'Item Metadata '. Delete this value.
Repeat this untill you read "Finished searching the registry".

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Searching through HKCU... I actually forgot I asked this question, now I have to find that computer to make sure this actually works. Thank you! This looks really promising!

Comment: Oh bah. I am sorry. It looks like everything has been upgraded to Microsoft Office Professional 2016, and I am not able to reproduce the issue with Office 2013 anymore. Thank you for contributing!